# Index Rebuild Cost - ALL vs. Individual

Tags: sql-server

Given a large table with...

- just under 1 billion rows
- clustered index (enabled)
- one or more unique indexes (enabled)
- 5+ non-clustered non-unique indexes (disabled)

What is the most cost and time effective way to rebuild the disabled indexes?

In other words, is it more cost effective to do an ALTER INDEX REBUILD ALL which includes the enabled indexes, or is it more cost effective to rebuild the disabled indexes individually?

If the REBUILD ALL scans the table once instead of scanning for each index to be rebuilt, and given the size of the table, I imagine it might be faster and far less IO intensive to use the REBUILD ALL instead of rebuilding indexes individually.

For some additional context, I am migrating a 5TB database to AWS RDS for SQL Server via AWS Data Migration Services (DMS). There are limitations negating native SQL backup/restore as a migration option.  I leave all clustered and unique indexes to eliminate duplicate records and to force the data to be sorted on the target. All other indexes are disabled to reduce IO and CPU load on the target during the full-load phase of the DMS tasks. Once a DMS task moves from full-load to the replication phase, I rebuild the disabled indexes.